# What's the exact mechanism that process transactions and promises in nearprotocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

According to near docs:

> Callbacks are executed when all the dependencies has returned values
> or errors. Since return values are also delivered asynchronously, the
> execution will be triggered when the last required dependency is
> processed on the callback account.

Are "dependencies" are other promises the called contract schedules? does it include callbacks?.

Is there some docs about that?

Where's the core code where dependencies are processed?

Does this (https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#transaction-status) affect dependency processing or just the rpc call?

---

P.S. I found some docs: https://nomicon.io/RuntimeSpec/Receipts.html

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies are other promises that have a callback. They can be any action types.

There are 3 types of execution results:

- A value, e.g. "true"
- Another promise, it means the dependency will now depend on the result of this promise.
- An error, when any action within a Receipt/promise fails.

Since to create a promise, you need gas, the execution eventually ends.